# How to get Data of Iframe and store it in MySQL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which opens a website.  I want to know what the user has clicked on the iframe. For example- The iframe opens yellowpages.com , I want to know what phone number has the user clicked on or which company has he clicked on? Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible due to Same Origin Policy

Comment: I couldn't figure out anything

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to spy on what a user does on another website, even if you put that website in a frame on your site.

If you had the cooperation of the other site, then it could bind an event listener to monitor clicks and then use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to inform your site across the frames.